# Order By: Returning unLIKE before LIKE?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This should be an easy one, but I am having a moment. Why does ORDER BY with LIKE sort the matching results as a higher value than the non-matching? To get the results I expect I have to mix ASC and DESC on what is otherwise the same data:

```
create table foo (name text);
select name from foo order by name like 'm%' desc, name;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"x" like 'm%' is FALSE; "motorcade" like 'm%' is TRUE; "FALSE" < "TRUE".

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union` for this...

```
select name from foo where name like 'm%' 
order by name desc
union all 
select name from foo where name not like 'm%' 
order by name asc
```

it will give result as per your requirement.. :)

---

added asc in second union select query ... just for more understandable statement ... without this(ASC) also query should give desired result..